# comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *') - C

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, void

Im trying to check if the index of an array has a value or not.

```
void * cols;
...
...

if (((int*)cols)[1]==NULL){
            counter++;
            columns++;

    }
else
{   
    value=((int*)cols)[1];
            fprintf(f, "Validation result from process id: %u. :column %d is invalid\n", (unsigned int)thread_10,value);

}
```

this gives me the warning " comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *') " . what am i doing wrong ? how can i check if the index is null or not?. Also i can't check for 0 because 0 is a valid value in my case meaning if a index holds the value 0 that means its valid.

Comment: Only pointers can be `NULL`. `((int*)cols)[1]` is an `int`, not a pointer. And there is no such thing as "an empty variable", so you can't check whether an array has some value assigned to it or not. You, the programmer, needs to keep track of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cols` is a pointer. After casting it with `int *` it is still a pointer, but now you are looking at it as a pointer to `int`. When writing `((int*)cols)[1]` you took your `void* cols`, casted it `int*` and then dereferenced it ,meaning you now look at an `int` and that's why you can't check for `NULL`.

`(int*)cols` might be `NULL`, or any other address so this is the variable you should check, and `((int*)cols)[1]` is the `int` value placed in the address `cols {some address} + sizeof(int)`

So, `if (((int*)cols)[1]==NULL)` should be if `(cols)==NULL)` *{it does not matter if it is `void*` or `int*` when checking for `NULL`}* and `value=((int*)cols)[1];` is just fine